# Laravel - Auxiliary method where to put it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a logging method, and I'd like to run this log every time an x-screen is opened.

In the log I will check if there is already a log on that day, if there is no saved and if there is only increment ...

But this function I will use in several controllers, what is the best place for me to put this methodo and make it accessible in all controllers?

Note: Using laravel 5.4

Comment: Note: a helper is not what I need

Comment: Maybe you can dispatch an event like 'ScreenWasOpened' and pass the name of the screen like this: event(new ScreenWasOpened($page)); Then register a listener that will do whatever it needs with that info (like logging if needed)

Comment: Sounds like middleware to me, but depends on your structure of course.  Why not add Middleware that throws an event, and then log the info asynchronously as per @EduardoPacios's suggestion?

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to read the middleware documentation and I'll answer later
Thank you for now!